# JSFIDDLE Errors

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

There are two errors in this coding, on line 3 and 9. I'm sure it is a simple mistake but I can not seem to find what is wrong with it.

**HTML CODE**

```
<h1 id="title">Enter the String</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="change()"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
function change(){
  var str = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if( str.length==0 ){
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }
  var arr = str.split();
  var map = {};
  for (int i= 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(map[arr[i]] == true){
      map[arr[i]] = map[arr[i]] || [];
      map[arr[i]].push(i+1);
    }
    else{
      map[arr[i]] = [];
      map[arr[i]].push(i+1);
    }
  }
  alert(map);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm removing your java tag... javascript is not the same as java

Comment: @YassinHH: That may be why he declared `int i` instead of `var i`... (This is the only syntax error that I can see, apart from `JAVASCRIPT CODE` not being valid JavaScript code.)

Comment: sorry about that @YassinHH and also i did not see any errors either but for some reason when it is written out in jsfiddle the program does not work an says there are 2 errors on line3 3 and 9?

Comment: The variable `i` in your for loop is not correctly identified. It should be `var i = 0`

Comment: @TomNolan yeah i changed that an it brings up another error for the line below it, and program still doesnt work, sorry if it is simple things to fix, this is my first assignment using java-script.

Comment: You're also calling variables outside your functions. For example, `str` is inside your `change` function. It's not a global variable and therefore cannot be called when you're declaring your `arr` variable.

Comment: @TomNolan https://cop3530.pbworks.com/w/page/97919971/Module%208%20-%20%20Hashing%20Part%201  that is the link to the assignment i am trying to do

Comment: @TomNolan awesome thank you so much, it works now, need to analyze it and see what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're goal of the function is, but when you reorganize the code so that you're not referencing variables that aren't defined, everything goes through:

```
function change() {
    var str = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
    if( str.length==0 ){
      alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    }
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    var map = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(map[arr[i]] == undefined) {
          map[arr[i]] = [i]
        }
        else{
            map[arr[i]].push(i)
        }
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(map));
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQwxbV

Based on what you sent me this is what it should look like...